# How to successively Crop THEN add multiple boxblur's to a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop, blur

I need to programmatically crop a video and *then* add ffmpeg boxblur to multiple regions of the cropped video.

(Once the 'croppedAndBoxblurred' video is completed, I then need to read the image file in nodejs.)

I have managed to do the following:

(i'm accessing a local binary ffmpeg library, hence the string format)

1. Crop the video using the following ffmpeg commands:

```
      [ "-i",
        `${path_to_video}`,
        "-filter:v",
        `crop=${width}:${height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}`,
        "-preset",
        "fast",
        "-progress",
        `${temp_log_file_path}`,
        `${path.join(temp_directory, "cropped-video.mp4")}`]
```

The listener (for the "progress=end" flag in the temp_log_file_path.txt) works fine.

2. I can also create a SINGLE boxblur using the following commands:

```
      [ "-i",
        `${path_to_cropped_video}`,
         "-filter_complex",
        `[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]`,
        `-map`,
        `[v]`,
        `${temp_log_file_path}`,
        `${path.join(temp_directory, "boxblurred-video.mp4")}`]
```

but i'm unable to combine the commands.

I've tried lots and lots of different combinations using the `ffmpeg` cli.

The following tests work individually:-

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/cropped.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test4.mp4


ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test5.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test6.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf crop=600:600:2:2 /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test3.mp4
```

None of these work:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mov  -filter_complex “crop=100:100:100:100,boxblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]” -map “[v]” /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/croppblur.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]crop=600:600:2:2[new]; [0:v][new]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]crop=600:600:2:2[new]” -map “[0:v][new]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf crop=“600:600:2:2[tmp]” -filter_complex “[0:v][tmp]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf crop=“600:600:2:2” -filter_complex “[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf “crop=600:600:2:2” -filter_complex “[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf crop=600:600:2:2 -filter_complex “[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test2.mp4

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter:v “crop=600:600:2:2” /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/titties.mp4
(No such filter crop)

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -vf crop=600:600:2:2 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]" -map "[v]" /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test4.mp4
(Filtergraph 'crop=600:600:2:2' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.)

ffmpeg -i /Users/fr/Desktop/media_folder/test1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[tmp]; [0:v][tmp]crop=600:600:2:2[new]” -map “[new]” /Users/fr/Desktop/review-media-images/test4.mp4
([AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fdecb910d40] Too many inputs specified for the "crop" filter)
```

**Question:**

What is the correct syntax to achieve this ???

Also, how would I add MULTIPLE boxblur regions to the cropped video i.e. to blur out different non-contiguous areas on the same video viewport ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to combine the 2 commands, just generalize the blur filtergraph. You currently have `-filter_complex` option:

```
[0:v]crop=200:200:100:100,boxblur=10[fg];\
[0:v][fg]overlay=100:100[v]
```

You can modify this with an additional crop filterchain, and offset the foreground crop parameters by the same amount:

```
[0:v]crop=${width}:${height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}[bg];\
[0:v]crop=200:200:${x_pos+100}:${y_pos+100},boxblur=10[fg];\
[bg][fg]overlay=100:100[v]
```

To add more blur boxes, you just need to repeat the last 2 lines with new labels. To add another box, do:

```
[0:v]crop=${width}:${height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}[bg];\
[0:v]crop=200:200:${x_pos+100}:${y_pos+100},boxblur=10[fg];\
[bg][fg]overlay=100:100[v]
[0:v]crop=200:200:${x_pos+200}:${y_pos+200},boxblur=10[fg1];\
[v][fg]overlay=100:100[v1]
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked really well using the ffmpeg cli. Still having problems with passing the strings into the first ```[...]``` function. using execFile in ffmpeg-static-electron. Will keep trying.